Height of flex container determined by specific child
on my page I have three divs next to each other. One main content and two sidebar type things. They all have dynamic content and no fixed heights.
What I want is that the main child determines the height of the container. And the two sidebar containers adhere to that. So the sidebars should be as high as needed, but not higher than the main-child. (If they have more content to show, then they should get a vertical scroll-bar instead)
What I have in my current solution is that the height of the container is determined by the tallest child. This is not what I want.
This codesandbox shows the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sidebar-height-92pgch
How can I achieve that the container height is only determined by the main-child?
Regards
Code snippets:
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }
      .container .main-child {
        flex-grow: 1;
        background-color: salmon;
      }
      .container .sidebar {
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 300px;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
    </style>

<body>
    <h1>Sidebar height problem</h1>
    <div>
      <p>
        Currently, the container height is always determined by the largest flex
        child (in the first example by the rightmost sidebar and in the second
        example by the main-child).
      </p>
      <p>
        What I want instead, is that only the main-child determines the height.
      </p>
      <p>
        The sidebars should be only as high as needed for their content, but
        <b>not</b> larger than the main-child. And if one of the sidebars is
        larger because of it's content, then it should have a scrollbar.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main-child">
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone,
        and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the
        bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in
        the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect myA
        wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone,
        and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the
        bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in
        the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my like
        these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am
        alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created
        for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so
        absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I
        neglect my. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot,
        which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my
        dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil
        existence, that I neglect my
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone,
        and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the
        bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in
        the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my
        talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present
        moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When,
        while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian
        sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees,
        and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary,
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="main-child">
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone,
        and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the
        bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in
        the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my
        talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present
        moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When,
        while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian
        sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees,
        and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw
        myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream; and, as I lie
        close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I
        hear the buzz of the little world among the stalks, and grow familiar
        with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I
        feel the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and
        the breath A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul,
        like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I
        am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was
        created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend,
        so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I
        neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at
        the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist
        than now. When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and
        the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage
        of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary,
        I throw myself down among the tall grass by the trickling stream; and,
        as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by
        me: when I hear the buzz of the little world among the stalks, and grow
        familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects and
        flies, then I feel the presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his
        own image, and the breath A wonderful serenity has taken possession of
        my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with
        my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this
        spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy,
        my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil
        existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a
        single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a
        greater artist than now. When, while the lovely valley teems with vapour
        around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the
        impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into
        the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among the tall grass by the
        trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown
        plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the little world among
        the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of
        the insects and flies, then I feel the presence of the Almighty, who
        formed us in his own image, and the breath A wonderful serenity has
        taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring
        which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of
        existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like
        mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense
        of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be
        incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I
        feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When, while the lovely
        valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the
        upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few
        stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down among
        the tall grass by the trickling stream; and, as I lie close to the
        earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz
        of the little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the
        countless indescribable forms of the insects and flies, then I feel the
        presence of the Almighty, who formed us in his own image, and the breath
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these
        sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone,
        and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the
        bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in
        the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my
        talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present
        moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. When,
        while the lovely valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian
        sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees,
        and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>


Please check Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

please, add your code samples that reproduce your issue  here, eventually  inside a snippet.
